# Is higher or lower resistance wire able to heat up more? Are there other factors?

Tags: power, wire, heat

Why is it that low resistance wire in vaporizers are considered to product more heat, yet for my engineering project thin high resistance chromium wire seems to heat up most?

According to P = IV and V = IR it does seem that lower resistance wire should create a higher wattage and therefore a higher heat output, yet in the process of designing a road heating system it seems that the thinnest high resistance wire creates the most heat. Am I missing some major key of thermodynamics? Or am I pulling some kind of black magic?

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/193824/10658

Comment: @user2489995 did you also measure the voltage across the resistive material?

Answer (score 4):

Part of the problem is "what do you mean, heat up more?" - higher temperature, or more heat - they are not the same thing. An incandescent bulb filament is much **hotter** than an electric stove element, but the electric stove element delivers a lot more **heat** (and power) unless the bulb in question is something huge and theatrical/industrial in nature.

Regardless, R is irrelevant unless and until you have a fixed or limited V or I.

For a fixed voltage with unlimited current, the lowest possible R will give the most POWER, as current will rise to infinity. Of course, that does not happen with real supplies, so the lowest R that allows full voltage to be supplied at maximum available current will give the most power.

Now, if you want the highest wire temperature, rather than the most power/heat, something very skinny and preferably made of tungsten and stashed in an inert gas or a vacuum will do nicely. If it needs to be in air, Kanthal or similar. If all you are doing is melting ice, wire type is not terribly challenging, since nearly any common wire type will do just fine boiling water so ice-melting temperatures are not too difficult.

For a fixed current, with unlimited voltage, the highest resistance will get you the most power, but again, practical supplies don't generally DO "unlimited voltage" and all sorts of unpleasant life-safety and plasma discharge related issues come up fairly soon as you crank up the voltage.

For practical devices, you generally have a supply limited in voltage and current, and you choose your heating element resistance to make the most effective use of those limits to get your job done - or determine that you can't and get the design changed so you can use (say) 480V 3-phase rather than 240V single-phase if you need more power than you can reasonably expect to get from 240V single-phase. Or you add a lot of thermal insulation so you can do the job with less power, or whatever. It's design, you solve it.

Likewise, you need to not burn out whatever your heating element is - when they melt, they tent to stop working (which is why I called out tungsten and kanthal - look up melting points, as well as for your nichrome.) You can dump 10 kilowatts into a 24 guage nichrome wire, but not for long.

If I infer correctly that your actual application is melting ice on road surfaces (a major waste of electric power that could far better be used to pump a fluid to pick up geothermal heat (or even burned-fuel heat) to perform the same task, but that's veering off-topic) then you need to be concerned with power delivery (each pound of ice requires a certain amount of heat to melt it) rather than particularly high temperature (you need an adequate SURFACE temperature for whatever rate of ice-melt you require, but it's not going to be 500°C...)

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and now my question is how do I find temperature from heat/power? If I have many different wires all outputting the same wattage how do I determine which will have the greatest temperature output?

Comment: Temperature of the WIRE or temperature of (I guess) some section of road the wire is thermally coupled to? If all wires are coupled to the same size section of road, the one with the most effective coupling will heat the road best. For just wires, the smallest one that does not simply turn into a puff of plasma when you turn the power on will be hottest, at least until some part of it turns into a puff of plasma.

Answer (score 3):

Any given resistor can dissipate the same amount of power. It just depends on the product of voltage and current \$P = V\cdot I\$.

Since \$V = I\cdot R\$ and \$I = \frac{V}{R}\$ the expression for the power can be rewritten as \$P = \frac{V^2}{R}\$ or as \$P=I^2\cdot R\$. The first equation suggests that a higher resistance would be better while the second shows that a lower resistance would be better. So it depends on the application if it is easier to generate a higher current or a higher voltage and you have to choose the resistor accordingly.

Comment: Mario, your point is sound.  But equations seem to be typoed  \$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} = I^2 R \$ .

Comment: So there is no difference at all in the heat generated by using high voltage vs high current. Also this might need a new post of it's own, but how is voltage generated vs. current. I feel as though both must work together.

Answer (score 3):

For a real world, linear power supply, it turns out that you get the max power out by using a resistive load whose value matches the internal resistance of the power supply.  That resistor value is the sweet spot, and lowering or raising the load resistance will diminish your power out.

Keep in mind, most real world linear power supplies were not designed to dissipate that much internal heat, so likely won't last long.

Answer (score 2):

What does "heat up more" mean?

Electrical power is the product of voltage and current. So assuming this wire is being driven by a voltage source, then a lower resistance will draw more power. "Power" is best thought of as "the rate of energy conversion", so you are converting some source of electrical energy into thermal energy.

How "hot" is say, 10W, or 10 joules per second of thermal energy? Power, in itself, doesn't give a temperature. What you can do is find the thermal mass of the material being heated and use that to calculate how many joules of thermal energy it will take to raise the temperature of that thing by some amount. So the power doesn't tell you how hot it will get: it just tells you the rate at which you can make it hotter.

Any hot thing will lose thermal energy to colder surroundings, under ordinary circumstances at a rate proportional to the temperature difference. That proportion is called thermal resistance. A higher thermal resistance is "better insulation": it means it will take a larger temperature difference to transfer thermal energy at a given rate.

With these you can calculate the thermal equilibrium: where the rate at which an object is gaining thermal energy from the electric heater equals the rate at which it is losing thermal energy to its surroundings.

Comment: Great answer! Could you show the math for someone who would want to raise the temp of a kiln (12 cubic inches) from 68° F to 2000° F using a common nichrome wire?

Comment: @DIYser I don't know if it would be so easy. We'd need to know the thermal resistance of the kiln. Also, I'm betting your objective isn't heating the kiln, but its contents. In theory the contents won't change the maximum temperature of the kiln if you wait long enough, but "long enough" might be a very long time. So you'll need to get the thermal characteristics of the contents also, and decide how fast you need to heat them.

Comment: Ok.  Let's say the thermal conductivity of the kiln zirconia is 3 Wm•K and the contents of the kiln will be 20 oz. of ordinary air-dried clay for firing to produce a ceramic object.  What would be the best way to do the calculations properly to make a heater out of a common nichrome wire?

Comment: @DIYser It's just a bunch of multiplication and division. Dimensional analysis will guard against errors. Not much related to electrical engineering, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, well, one would have to solve the physics problem first to develop an electrical solution, I suppose.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to mention that if heaters is fed by a *current* source, a higher-resistance wire will heat up more.  If two heaters are in series, they will both receive the same current, so the higher-resistance one will heat up more, but if they are in paralle, they'll receive the same voltage and the lower-resistance one will heat more.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it that low resistance wire in vaporizers are considered to product more heat

Because of so-called mechanical mods. These run directly off of the battery voltage, so lower resistance means higher current, which in turn means higher power. In the old days, if you wanted a poweful vape, you had to use a mechanical mod, simply because the regulated mods on the market weren't powerful enough.

After high power regulated (constant power) mods became available, the notion of "low resistance equals much power" stuck in the vaping community, despite the fact that it was no longer true.

Also, thicker wire (low resistance wire) has higher thermal mass and heats up slower, which gives the user more control over the temperature, simply by varying the time the power switch is held down. An atomizer that heats up too fast can lead to dry hits - 
overheated e-liquid tastes horrible, and is particularly unhealthy. And that's the *other* reason why thicker wire is still popular.

> yet for my engineering project thin high resistance chromium wire seems to heat up most?

For a given power, the heat is the same; The heat equals the power. You can even say that the heat *is* the power.

> According to P = IV and V = IR it does seem that lower resistance wire should create a higher wattage and therefore a higher heat output,

For a fixed voltage, yes.

> yet in the process of designing a road heating system it seems that the thinnest high resistance wire creates the most heat.

For a fixed power, no. But perhaps the road heating systems work at higher voltages and lower currents? That might be more efficient, causing less loss in the power supply. That's just speculation on my part, though. It depends on the voltages and currents involved, the design of the power supply and the nature of the power source. Also, wire costs money, so using thinner wire might be more cost effective.

> Am I missing some major key of thermodynamics? Or am I pulling some kind of black magic?

No room for black magic in electronics, but there is much room for various practical considerations which aren't always accounted for mathematically, simply because that's not always necessary.